# What does PDF of normal distribution represents?

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function

I have a basic question about the probability density function of the standard normal distribution $X\sim N(0,1)$. I understand that the cumulative distribution function for x is $P(X\le x)$ (in R language it can be obtained by `pnorm(x,mean =0, sd =1)`). However, I don't understand what $f(x)$ represents (in R:  `dnorm(x,mean =0, sd =1)`) ?
$$
f(x)   =   \frac{1} {  \sqrt{2\pi } }   e^{  -x^2/  2}
$$

Note that for a discrete random variable, like the binomial distribution, it is equivalent to $P(Y=x)$.

Comment: You can find the explanation from internet or textbook. For example, https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/97/

Comment: Thanks for the link. According to the definition, f(x) does not represent anything, only it is helpful in finding getting P(X<x).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the density is dnorm not pnorm

The density is simply the derivative (rate of change) of the distribution function “pnorm” at the value specified